# Removing an object from an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I want to remove an element from the `ArrayList` whose length is equal to the number passed as an integer. My code is as follows. When run, the programs throws `UnsupportedOperationException` in the line when `remove()` method is used. Actually, it is a codingbat problem.

```
public static List<String> wordsWithoutList(String[] words, int len) {    
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    list = Arrays.asList(words);

    for(String str : list) {
        if(str.length() == len) {
            list.remove(str);
        }
    }
    return l;       
}
```

Comment: Ok, and what's your question?

Comment: i wanna know why it's throwing the above exception

Comment: you should cast to `(List<String>) Arrays.asList(words);`

Comment: you can not remove a element from a list, while you are iterating the same list

Answer (score 10):

The list returned by `asList` isn't an `ArrayList` -- it doesn't support modification.

You need to do

```
public static List<String> wordsWithoutList(String[] words, int len) {

    List<String> l = new ArrayList<String>( Arrays.asList(words) );

    for( Iterator<String> iter = l.iterator(); iter.hasNext(); ){
        String str = iter.next();
        if(str.length()==len){
            iter.remove();
        }
    }
    return l;       
}
```

So two things:

- Make a modifiable copy of the array returned by `asList` using the `ArrayList` constructor.
- Use the iterator's `remove` to avoid a `ConcurrentModificationException`.

It was pointed out that this can be inefficient, so a nicer alternative is:

```
List<String> l = new ArrayList<String>(str.length());
                                   //  ^^ initial capacity optional
for( String str : words )
    if( str.length()!=len)
        l.add(str);

return l;
```

Comment: Curious, is this a good practice (modifying the list on which you are iterating)? or a new list should be created where we should add elements which we need and return that new ArrayList?

Comment: I think it's cleaner to create a new list and add items to it.

Comment: @zengr Either strategy works, with an `ArrayList` removing items from the middle moves all the following items in the list, so if there are many items to remove or the list is large, it will be better to use the copy strategy.

Comment: @trutheality
your code works just fine but when i replace your for loop with the following code, it throws ConcurrentModificationException. Can you tell me why is that? Because to my understanding, the syntax of removing an object from the object is correct and the logic is also valid but it still throws exception. Thanks

for(String str: l){
   if(str.length()==len){
    l.remove(str);
   }
  }

Comment: @zengr My point is that it's certainly not bad practice because that is exactly what the iterator's add and remove methods are for.

Comment: @nick-s That is why I am using the iterator: when you are iterating over a list like that, which internally uses it's own iterator, you can't use the list's remove or add methods inside the loop because the iterator needs to know where the next element is -- if you were allowed to remove it, or add an element in front of it, you might break the iterator.